# Kotlin compiler complains about using a SPeL expression in a property definition. WHY?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-el

When I try to use a SPeL expression to inject a value it works from in Java but NOT in Kotlin. The compiler says

> Error:(13, 25) Kotlin: An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class DeDup(@Value("#{new java.io.File('${roots}')}") val roots: Set<File>,
                 @Value("algo") val hashAlgo: String,
                 @Value("types")val fileTypes: List<String>) {

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 SpringApplication.run(DeDup::class.java, *args)
}
```

Mmm... news flash Kotlin compiler: It IS a constant! The compiler clearly knows it's a SPeL expression and doesn't like it.

My questions:

1. Why doesn't Kotlin like SPeL? This is a construction injection (or is it) and doesn't violate immutability.
2. Is this a compiler bug? The message is irrefutably wrong.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`${roots}` inside a String in Kotlin is a [string template](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates), therefore that String is not a constant.

If you want the String to contain those actual characters and not be interpreted as a template, you'll have to escape the `$`:

```
@Value("#{new java.io.File('\${roots}')}")
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks